# How to pass place holder of images created in controller to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to create a placeholder of images and pass to view to display them. As below:

```
While(Some condition)
{
   _placeholder.Controls.Add(Img);
}
```

Pass this place holder to view and display it.

If i do only one image I am able to display it as follows:

```
 <img src="<%=Url.Action('ActionName', 'ControllerNAme')%>" alt="" />
```

But there is no tag to call placeholder/

Thanks

Comment: dont understiand what this statement is doing _placeholoder.Contr..,
but you could use db to archive images and getting them by one with FileResult type in a view

Comment: I have a plug-in which reads images from a place holder and display them in certain format. So now i want to make use of that plug-in. For that i have to get my images in a place holder. First line of my code does that in controller. But i dont know how to pass that placeholder in to view.